# When can I ask my questions again?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Due to duplicate of questions, I wasn't able to ask questions. Like in other sites, I thought only the questions that are most recent will be answered..so I posted the question again not knowing the bounty system. When will I be able to ask questions again?

Comment: It is not because of duplicates, see the link that Arjan provide @Priya and you only have 2 duplicate so far, that isn't the case even if it is true.

Comment: @Priya if you really see the "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account" message you won't be able to ask anymore, it's permanent.

Comment: so what should I do now? can you pls giude me?

Comment: @Priya if you have strong argument why you shouldn't be banned, explain this in email to the team. See footer of the page. (contact us link)

Comment: @YOU, I guess the OP meant: because (s)he *posted* duplicates and hence probably deleted earlier versions. Bad behavior, on ANY web site, I'd say.

Comment: @Priya, did you *read* that question that is linked above? Please tell us what is not clear so we can improve that. But please read it first.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know any sites where you're supposed to just keep posting the same question over and over. It's crazy how many people do that here on SO and blame it on "experience with other sites". That's just bad etiquette everywhere. I've never been to a forum or Q&A site of any kind that didn't have a search feature. It's never only the questions that are the most recent that will be answered.

Comment: @Arjan --I read the question linked above and found that the cause might be because I have too many deleted questions or something might be incorrect the way I am framing questions. I do not have many down votes associated to my questions, but I think that it should be the deleted questions. Is there a way I can reactivate my account?

I apologize for any inconvenience but the only reason I would delete a question was to clean up any questions without a proper answer hanging out there. I had no idea that I was not supposed to delete many questions. I have no intentions of abusing privileges?

Comment: If I know the reasons I promise I would definitely not repeat my mistakes in the future.

Comment: Upon further examination, I agree that this does seem a little strange. The questions that show up in your profile don't appear to be that low quality. I've certainly seen far worse from users that are not barred from asking questions. There must be something in the questions you've had deleted, either by yourself or for reasons of moderation. Those wouldn't show up in your profile, but would still affect the algorithm that determines question-asking bans.

Comment: @Priya - maybe you could consider changing your behaviour by *contributing* to the community and *answering* questions. You have 34 questions and only 1 answer so far... one redeeming feature i do see is that you seem to have a good accept rate on the questions you haven't deleted.

Comment: @Cody, it's my understanding (but I could be wrong!) that deleted questions are kind of interpreted as "were apparently not of much value", and hence "should not have been posted to start with", and hence "must have been bad for the communities". Even if true, I don't know how much that counts towards being banned from asking questions.

Comment: Also, @Priya, your questions have probably been asked before—at least *this* one has, many times. So you may very well still find your questions answered by learning how to search the sites. (But: beware that these site are not forums, so don't mess up existing questions by posting "answers" that are not answers at all.) Success!

Comment: @Arjan: I wasn't at all disagreeing with that assessment. In fact, I completely *agree* with it, not only as being the de facto interpretation, but also as being the *correct* one. My point was only that the questions I can see from the user's profile don't appear to be that horrible, so those that triggered the ban must be ones that have been deleted. I don't believe the asking ban is triggered by asking too many questions without providing any answers; both asking and answering are valuable functions of the site, and Jeff has said that we aren't here to force people to answer questions.

Comment: Just wanted to make clear that even deleting *good quality* questions *might* make those questions be considered as being bad. (But I'm sure we understand each other, @Cody, despite my long-winded earlier explanation `;-)`)