# Show some indication that account is banned from asking new questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, 10k-tools, post-ban

It would be nice if we could see somehow that someone is getting the infamous "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account" message when trying to ask new question, same way that we can see when someone is suspended when viewing the user profile.

It can appear as the same red bar as in the suspended account, or something else.. maybe only via the moderation tools for 10K+ members.

Right now when someone ask [such question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89082/when-can-i-ask-my-questions-again) we can only *assume* this is the case but can't know for sure.

**Edit:** as we can all clearly see, there is a steady rise in programming questions posted here on Meta by users who are getting banned from asking questions on the main site. While we can handle this easily, it would still be useful to show some indication that the user is question banned on the main site even if just so that people won't waste time trying to offer guidance to those users.

Comment: What other possible causes are there? I mean, you say we can only assume this is the case, but if it's a uniquely identifying symptom, then that assumption isn't really an assumption.

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: @Cody dunno, maybe bug, maybe they mean something else.. better to be sure IMO

Comment: @Jeff purpose of information - account that can't post questions is "crippled" so in my opinion people should know about it. For example such user (who can't ask new questions) might ask questions as comments on existing questions or answers so quick look in the profile will reveal the reason for this "weird" behavior.

Comment: @shadow do you have any examples of this, or is it a theory?

Comment: @Jeff just theory at the moment. Guess only time will tell though.

Comment: Oh wow, @Cody, Shadow Wizard might have been on to something. Apparently there's also [a "70 question limit reached" block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/70-question-limit) nowadays.

Comment: @Jeff, because you secretly introduced a 70 question limit as well? :-)

Comment: @Arjan thanks for the heads up, as usual! For the record I'm totally for this new feature and it's great but very different from the permanent question ban - IMO the suggested indication shouldn't be applied in such case.

Comment: According to comments [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103292/offensive-username/103320#103320), moderators cannot see some indication either.

Comment: @Arjan nice find.. wonder if it will make any difference though.

Comment: +1 This would also be useful in cases where users are asking their off-topic questions here because they are banned from the main site. I give people the benefit of the doubt, but [apparently I shouldn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140244/refresh-iframe-page). I think something on the user card would come in handy, even if it's only visible to users with a certain rep.

Comment: Personally, I think this should not be publicly visible, only for diamonds and *maybe* trusted users. That suspension is publicly visible is one thing, slapping a banner onto someone which reads "this guy sucks at asking/answering questions" is something completely different.

Comment: @Uri Bobby - good point, maybe just small indication not the same banner used to show user is in suspension.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I was not talking about how small or not that notification should be, but what message it would deliver. That *message* should not be public. You can color the whole profile in red, that's fine with me, as long as only diamonds see it that way.

Comment: My account has been banned from asking questions again for the 4th time ... Stack need to do something about this ... its irritating

Comment: @Yatin that's not relevant to what I suggest anyway from quick look it's more likely you share IP that is getting banned, do you browse the site from work or shared computer?

Comment: i mostly browse at work but browse at home too

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I still don't see any justification for showing this other than your curiosity, we still have no plans to expose this.  Not withstanding the lack of a reason *for* it, there's a decent performance reason against it: it's a runtime check that's non-trivial.

Comment: @Nick OK guess this is fair enough and your judgement after all. To make it official, you can change to status-declined post the reasoning and I'll grant the bounty. Bad news is still news! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see us ever exposing this information.  The only reason for displaying it is to say "hey this person sucks"...that doesn't help anyone and [isn't really what we're after](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/).

Besides that, there are technical reasons.  It's a *runtime* check, which adds page load time to the profile for those that can see it (not even moderators)...so that would either be a slower page load for profiles (*never!*) or a re-architecting how the check works (not worth it, without a good reason for displaying it in the first place).

Comment: Cheers Nick, the first reason is more than enough - never intended to point fingers and glad this place has managers with enough vision to know where to navigate in time of need.