# Offensive Username

Tags: support, display-names

I'm not a prude - but [f***vimmeanpeople](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904241) seems like quite a rude and unacceptable username. Since we can't flag users - just questions - is it possible to make this username something a little more innocuous?

Edit: Ah, it seems he didn't learn the first time. Came back with [f***meanpeopleingeneral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904257). How original.

Comment: Typically you just flag one of the user's posts at random if you want to flag something about that user specifically

Comment: And furthermore, the tiny fraction of vim people who are mean hardly seems worthy of making a statement about.

Comment: @Rick: Yeah, but they all deny the holy truth of emacs...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A moderator already renamed that account.
The user then created [another account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904257/namelessuser) with a different Mailinator address (which I renamed) and asked the same question.

If this recurs, we'll need an IP ban.

Comment: It has recurred. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136670/where-to-find-code-for-interpreting-c-escape-sequences#

Comment: Banned until Aug 2012.

Answer (score 6):

As all three accounts are clearly the same person, I've [merged them together](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904241).

Comment: That will probably trigger the automatic post ban on IP address. Nice.

Comment: @Arjan - That's also what I figured, which made it the simplest solution to all the issues.

Comment: I suspect that an automatic ban would need one or two more questions.

Comment: @SLaks, am I right to assume that moderators can see if a post-ban is in place? (If not, then [Show some indication that account is banned from asking new questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89084/show-some-indication-that-account-is-banned-from-asking-new-questions) might be more useful than I would have imagined.)

Comment: @Arjan: Not that I know of.

Comment: The user was "temporarily banned" until Aug of 2012.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a very short list of users names that [aren't acceptable](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/192662).

Occasionally there are [names](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/192662) that contain foul language, use hate speech, or refer to body parts.

The owners can decide a few words that they simply don't want to show up on their site.

Beyond a very short list, any words on a slightly longer list should automatically notify the site's moderator (and if the change is network-wide, also the moderators here) that they should look at the name change, possibly even approve it before it goes live.

That way people can write whatever for a username and their free speech rights would be respected without blasting everyone with foul language or hate speech.