# Inappropriate username and/or gravatars.

Tags: discussion, display-names, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flag abusive users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)

*I'm not sure if there is a post about this already. I searched my title text and the first two pages returned nothing useful, so here goes:*

I have just come a crossed a user with (imo) a questionably inappropriate username and gravatar match-up ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/23875/dropped-on-japan ).  I was wondering what (if any) was the course of action when these are found? Although the particular case here does not overly offend me, I can see how it is offensive to others. I have also seen in the past racial and profanity in gravatars and have reported those directly to mods via the chat system (should that be the course of action here as well?)

I guess what I am really looking for is a "flag user" button or option on the main site (which I cannot find).

tl;dr - I'm curious to know how to report inappropriate usernames and/or gravatars.

Comment: Tasteless? Yes. Uncouth? Yes. Inappropriate? Nope.

Comment: Meant to be Offensive === Inappropriate. (in my books at least)

Comment: How do you know it's *meant* to be offensive? I don't think being offensive is the only thing you can be trying to do by referencing Little Boy.

Comment: It is a touchy subject, I can discuss Hitler without meaning to offend but I surly know I will offend so it is best to avoid these topics until a proper medium is available.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117596/possibly-offensive-usernames and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103292/offensive-username

Comment: ahh see that is why my search for "inappropriate" returned nothing :) thanks @Shog9

Answer (score 2):

Just pick one of their questions/answers at random and report it with a custom flag.  There is no way to put in a report flag directly on the profile for a user without the context of a post.