# Will I get a notification after my post ban will be removed?

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

I am currently banned from giving answers on Stack Overflow, and I want to know if there will be some kind of notification after the ban will get removed?

Comment: @gnat Hey gnat, please read my question again - this is not a duplicate. I was asking (and got answered below) about  the end ban period notification and not about "When does the question ban get applied"

Comment: have you given a read to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252645/165773) over there? It explains in exact details how ban works and why it is technically impossible to have any kind notification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show some indication that account is banned from asking new questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89084/show-some-indication-that-account-is-banned-from-asking-new-questions), also read the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) to make your own calculations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no kind of notification, since the ban will never be removed automatically after a certain period of time. There are two ways to get out of the ban:

- improve your existing posts; if they get enough upvotes, the ban will be lifted.
- regardless of the ban, you can make one new post every six months. Make it count, if it is well-received it'll help in lifting the ban.

Comment: thank you but my ban is not for asking the question, it is about answering someone else question, basically, I can only see the ban after writing my answer(it is kind of time wasted if i can't post the answer)

Comment: That doesn't matter, if I recall correctly. It's just that question bans are much more common; that's why most of the FAQ texts are aimed at question banned people.

Comment: so, if I I understand you correctly, even that it is different ban than posting question I will get the option of answering every 6 months

Comment: @TamirAbutbul Yes, answer banning is really answer rate limiting to once every six months. That answer might or might not get you out of the ban. If it doesn't, you get to try again after another 6 months.

Answer (score 7):

No, the system checks when you try to post an answer (or a question if you're question banned). In any case you'll still be able to post once every six months, so if you do that make it a good one as that's an opportunity to get out of the ban if that post gets upvoted.

Best advice is to improve and undelete your old posts. Deleted posts can't garner any new votes so they do tend to weigh you down.